# Unexpected character (i) at position 0. - JSON Parsing with Java

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "0" : {
        "upc" : "00000000005",
        "name" : "Weighable Soup Cups",
        "location" : "5310ed21d5dc7aaa0343a932"
    },
    "1" : {
        "upc" : "00000000011",
        "name" : "OF Reuseable Bags",
        "location" : "5310ed21d5dc7aaa0343a932"
    }
}
```

Thats a snippet of the JSON I am trying to parse. Here is the code I am using:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse("items.json");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject structure = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("0");
        System.out.println(structure.get("upc"));



    }

}
```

For some reason throws an unexpected character (i) at position 0 error. As far as I know of the JSON file is formatted correctly for parsing and the code is solid, so I don't understand why this will not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JSONParser#parse(String)` expects a JSON string, not a file name.

You can use the overloaded method that expects a `Reader` and provide an `InputStreamReader` which wraps a `FileInputStream`.

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("items.json")));
```

Comment: Or just a `FileReader` for simplicity.