# Error reading json file in java

Tags: java, json

I searched for this issue on the site but couldn't find one. May I know what am I missing here?

```
package com.json;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.util.Iterator;  
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;  
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;  
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;  
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;  

public class JsonTest {  

 public static void main(String[] args) {  

  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();  

  try {  

   Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("E://file.json"));  

   JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;  

   String nameOfCountry = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");  
   System.out.println("Name Of Country: "+nameOfCountry);  

   long population = (Long) jsonObject.get("Population");  
   System.out.println("Population: "+population);  

   System.out.println("States are :");  
   JSONArray listOfStates = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("States");  
   Iterator<String> iterator = listOfStates.iterator();  
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
    System.out.println(iterator.next());  
   }  

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  } catch (IOException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  } catch (ParseException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }  

 }  
}
```

---

{"Name":"EX","Population":1000000,"States":["MP","MH","RN"]}

---

Error: Unexpected character (ï) at position 0.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)

Comment: Is that the *actual* contents of the JSON file? My suspicion is that your file has a "Lowercase I with Umlaut" (ï) hidden in it somewhere (possibly in the word "Population") and you haven't pasted the actual contents here, obscuring the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144848/unexpected-character-i-at-position-0-json-parsing-with-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message show a weird character `ï` at position 0.

Your JSON file has a `UTF-8` [BOM (byte order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), which starts with byte `EF`, that in code page `ISO-8859-1` is the `ï` character.

Save your JSON file in `ISO-8859-1`, i.e. not in `UTF-8`. Java API's don't support BOM's.

Alternatively, save in `UTF-8` *without* a BOM, and read in Java as `UTF-8`.

Comment: Changed the file type to ANSI and the error disappeared. And!